# How to import the same file into mysql which has been uploaded?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i am trying to import data into mysql by uploading a text file.
I had written both the file upload and mysql import code in different files now i am trying to merge my code and I want to upload a file and at the same time want my code to import its data into mysql database.
I tried to paste down the import code after the upload and replace `fopen('static-file')` to `fopen('$FILES_["file"],"r"')`. But this did not work.

So please tell me how do I do both upload and import at same time.

**Below is My Upload Code**:

```
<?php
 include_once 'dbconfig.php';
 if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
 {    

$file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$folder="uploads/";

// new file size in KB
$new_size = $file_size/1024;  
// new file size in KB

// make file name in lower case
$new_file_name = strtolower($file);
// make file name in lower case

$final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(file,type,size) VALUES('$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
    mysqli_query($connection,$sql);


    ?>
    <script>
    alert('successfully uploaded');
   // window.location.href='index.php?success';
    </script>
    <?php


}
else
{
    ?>
    <script>
    alert('error while uploading file');
    window.location.href='index.php?fail';
    </script>
    <?php
  }

}

 ?>
```

This Is My Import Code for MYSQL:

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hiren");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }


        $handle = fopen("./uploads/imp.dat", "r");
      if ($handle) {
          while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

               $lineArr = explode("\t", "$line");
               var_dump($lineArr); // to make sure array is ok

               // instead assigning one by onb use php list -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php            
               list($emp_id, $date_data, $abc, $def, $entry, $ghi) = $lineArr;

               // and then insert data
               mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `daily_data2` (emp_id, date_data, abc, def, entry, ghi) 
      VALUES ('$emp_id', '$date_data', '$abc', '$def', '$entry', '$ghi')");
          }

          fclose($handle);
      }

        ?>
```

Comment: If you have the file on your server already, why don't you change the line `$handle = fopen("./uploads/imp.dat", "r");` to `$handle = fopen("./uploads/my_uploaded_file", "r");`? (I mean so that you use a variable to replace the file name with the uploaded file name)

Comment: Worth mentioning that I could easily erase your entire database by uploading a malicious text file. Look up "how do I prevent SQL injection in PHP" on this site for details. Also, PDO is far easier to use than mysqli.

Comment: thank you very much @miken32 . i will surely take note of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously opening up `fopen('$FILES_["file"],"r"')` isn't going to work, since that's an array (assuming you meant `$_FILES["file"]` of course.) And even if you tried opening up `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` it wouldn't work – what do you suppose [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) is doing?

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload'])) {
    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $folder="uploads/";

    // new file size in KB
    $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
    // new file size in KB

    // make file name in lower case
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    // make file name in lower case

    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

    if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file)) {
        $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(file,type,size) VALUES('$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
        mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

        $handle = fopen($folder.$final_file, "r");
        if ($handle) {
            while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
                $lineArr = explode("\t", "$line");
                var_dump($lineArr); // to make sure array is ok
                // instead assigning one by onb use php list -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php            
                list($emp_id, $date_data, $abc, $def, $entry, $ghi) = $lineArr;

                // and then insert data
                mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `daily_data2` (emp_id, date_data, abc, def, entry, ghi) 
  VALUES ('$emp_id', '$date_data', '$abc', '$def', '$entry', '$ghi')");
            }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    ?>
    <script>
    alert('successfully uploaded');
   // window.location.href='index.php?success';
    </script>
    <?php
    }
    else {
    ?>
    <script>
    alert('error while uploading file');
    window.location.href='index.php?fail';
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```